# How would the water cycle work on a planet with barely any atmosphere?

Tags: atmosphere, weather, water

See title.
My world is far away from any stars so radiation is of no worry but a very active volcanic system keeps the temperature at similar rates to our planet. The lack of an atmosphere stops any CO2 from being in the atmosphere and it mostly exist in the form of lakes on the planet surface

Comment: How would a planet with active volcanism not develop an atmosphere? Is the planet small with low gravity? I'm not usually a fan of judging the back story, but since @L.Dutch provided a good answer, I'm wondering about how the conditions exist in the first place. Is is possible for volcanism to keep the crust warm without spewing stuff into the sky somewhere?

Comment: CO2 doesn't have a liquid phase except at very high pressures, so there's no way to have lakes of it on the surface unless there was a very thick atmosphere, much thicker than Earth's.

Comment: If a "very active volcanic system" keeps the planetary temperature similar to that of Earth, there is no way that CO2 will be liquid.  Combine that with (for some reason) a lack of atmosphere, and you have a low pressure, high temperature world which would force any CO2 in the system to be a gas.

Comment: Adding to the holes already poked by others, your planet cannot maintain its surface temperature without an atmosphere, because you need an atmosphere to insulate heat. Look at Mars, where water is as hard as rock, or Io, the airless moon, the most volcanically active body in our solar system, where volcanic hotspots immediately give way to sulfurous frost. It’s a land of fire and ice because there is no atmosphere to distribute what little heat the volcanoes generate. You also need atmospheric pressure for water to remain liquid and not immediately evaporate, as it does on Mars.

Comment: "The lack of an atmosphere stops any CO2 from being in the atmosphere and it mostly exist in the form of lakes...": as others have pointed out, this makes no sense. The CO2 would **be** the atmosphere, along with some quantity of water vapor. You need around 70 atm of CO2 to make liquid CO2 lakes stable near earthlike temperatures (at which point you'll have a combined water and CO2 cycle), and over 31 °C it won't liquefy at all.

Answer (score 19):

If there is no atmosphere there will be no liquid water, and no water cycle.

As you can see in the [water phase diagram](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=34865054)

[image]

water needs at least 10 mbar to be in the liquid phase. Lower than that and your planet will only have ice (which will slowly sublimate) or vapor, which will be lost to space.

Comment: Maybe OP could have greasy lakes?  Lakes of ice covered with a film of alkanes?   The alkanes would prevent sublimation.  Also you could skate in your regular shoes,  which I have to think would be a plus for this planet.

Comment: @Willk alkanes are pretty volatile themselves. You'd need for the ice to be exclusively coated in quite long-chain alkanes that are solid or nearly so, and for those to for some reason never be split into lighter alkanes. Worse, heat in the presence of water is likely to do just that.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff - tar and oil bubble up from the planet's greasy heart.  It is like the La Brea tar pits but the whole planet, and I include the floating statues of woolly mammoths.  The short chain stuff disappears as you say.  What is left is Vaseline and asphalt that spreads into slick evaporationproof layers.

Comment: @Willk but the short chain stuff wouldn't disappear, it'd form an atmosphere.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff true too for the water, no?

Comment: @Willk Quite. This would produce a CO2/water/hydrocarbon atmosphere. Almost entirely CO2, if there's actually liquid CO2 present...something like a cool Venus with added hydrocarbons. Probably form some carbon monoxide too, in equilibrium with the rest of the mix, and hydrogen which will relatively quickly be lost, making the atmosphere tend more Venus-like over time...though it might freeze out as volcanism slows before that gets very far.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Lets begin, with elephant in the room.

Atmosphere is extremely vital for a planet's temperature cycle.

Lets see what atmosphere actually does.

Heat distribution to prevent night sides of planet to freeze and day side of the planet to burn.

Scattering the light and therefore preventing potential blindness or boiling your eye when you look at a star.

Holding heat and gas in itself to cycle them back to the planets ecosystem.

Creating varied pressure to keep materials liquid or solid, creating weather effects.

Assuming your world has little to no atmosphere, heat would not distribute equally and around a small part of the volcano would be extremely hot, other places would be extremely cold. Because, this planet is so far away from a star.

Lets assume we have regular volcanoes that lets out large amount of heat. Now, by nature of the heat, you need to have a matter for heat to spread.

If you insist of having no atmosphere, then your people has either built in zero atmosphere suit like bodies, or there is a powerful magic/technology there. Both option, does not require a natural water cycle which, your planet simply would not have. Then maybe only water cycle you could see would be regulated by mages/engineers+scientists

In this context, you either need an atmosphere, or need something like a ocean. Any liquid works basically.

Next, if there was no atmosphere, then... evaporated water would either form a pseudo-atmosphere and eventually with volcanic gasses, this would turn into a full fledged atmosphere, or water would turn to gas due to lack of atmosphere pressure.
Again same lack of pressure, combined with a lack of enough matter to hold the humidity, water would slowly gather around the planet or just leave the planet's gravity and go to space.